# Puzzle Construction Resources

Tags: discussion

What resources that are online are good for making visuals for puzzles? What are some good resources for making puzzles in general?

Comment: @Mithrandir Link is the answer to my question, but isn't in itself a question

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. Are you objecting simply because the dup-target is not technically written in the form of a question?

Comment: This variant does raise the question, is there value in adding some "visual tools" to the existing puzzling tools list? (eg. links to paint.net, gimp, inkscape, krita, etc)... arguably not since they're not puzzle specific, but still may be useful to people.

Comment: @Rubio That's a community wiki, not a question

Comment: .... and...?  Why does this distinction matter or need to be pointed out? It is a “question” post insofar as the site is concerned, which provides as table of contents; there are answers below it which hold the actual resources. This layout allows simpler linking to section content from table of contents. Beyond that, its self-description as a community wiki doesn’t make its information somehow ineligible to answer this present question, nor does it put it out of reach of being a dup target.

Comment: @Rubio, okay, I think that I was finding issue with the fact that the link to that basically answers my question, and it's getting marked a dup

Comment: Isn't that exactly what being a dupe entails? If your question is already answered elsewhere, then it's a dupe. (Still a good question though - I'm not sure why someone downvoted it.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor, the difference between this and what I consider a dupe is that the simple act of providing the link answers my question, not so much that the linked question (actually a community wiki) is the same as my question.